# Use rehype-raw in react-markdown to parse HTML element the type is not match

Tags: reactjs, typescript, markdown, react-markdown

I'm using typescript in my react project, however when I use [this](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown#appendix-a-html-in-markdown) code snippet I get an error

```
<ReactMarkdown rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]}>
   {content}
</ReactMarkdown>





Type '(options?: void | Options | undefined) => void | Transformer<Root, Root>' is not assignable to type 'Pluggable<any[], Settings>'.
  Type '(options?: void | Options | undefined) => void | Transformer<Root, Root>' is not assignable to type 'Plugin<any[], Settings>'.
    Type 'void | Transformer<Root, Root>' is not assignable to type 'void | Transformer'.
      Type 'Transformer<Root, Root>' is not assignable to type 'void | Transformer'.
        Type 'Transformer<Root, Root>' is not assignable to type 'Transformer'.
          Types of parameters 'node' and 'node' are incompatible.
```

any thoughts about that type error?

Comment: See https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype/discussions/63

Comment: Thanks! looks like this workaround is the only option, until `react-markdown` take care of it

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error. I fixed it by add a Type Assertions `as any` for `rehypePlugins`

```js
<Markdown
  rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw] as any}
>
  {content}
</Markdown>
```

it works now. hope it will works for you as well.