# React-Markdown Next.js 13 does not render markdown properly, rehypePlugins elements are also ignored

Tags: reactjs, next.js, markdown, next.js13, react-markdown

I am trying to implement markdown on my blog built in Next.js 13 using react-markdown and rehypeRaw to allow HTML in it. I am using "use client" in this file.
However, my text only shows up when I use markdown (#, ##, etc.) and heading levels are ignored, it's always the same small size. Just to clarify, styling with stars like **strong** works. When I try to use rehypeRaw like this:

```
<ReactMarkdown
        // @ts-expect-error
        rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]}
      >
    <h1> yessss</h1>
</ReactMarkdown>
```

Nothing shows up in the html tree, I receive this error on the  line:

```
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I just want to be able to use HTML and tailwindCSS with that inside of my markdown content. Or since this is just content that only I am allowed to post should I use dangerouslySetInnerHTML? I know that at least that solution works with Tailwind as I tested it. Would that be a vulnerability even though I am the only person with auth access to this website?

`// @ts expect error`  is what many GitHub issues describe as a workaround for rehypePlugins throwing this error:

```
Type '(options?: Options | null | undefined) => (tree: Root, file: VFile) => Root' is not assignable to type 'Pluggable<any[]>'.
  Type '(options?: Options | null | undefined) => (tree: Root, file: VFile) => Root' is not assignable to type 'Plugin<any[], any, any>'.
    Type '(tree: Root, file: VFile) => Root' is not assignable to type 'void | Transformer<any, any>'.
      Type '(tree: Root, file: VFile) => Root' is not assignable to type 'Transformer<any, any>'.
```

I also followed the accepted answer here to be able to properly render regular markdown:
[react-markdown don´t render Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74607419/react-markdown-don%c2%b4t-render-markdown)

Answer (score 0):

I have answer a familiar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77762348/7262646

```js
<ReactMarkdown
        // @ts-expect-error
        rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw] as any}
      >
    <h1> yessss</h1>
</ReactMarkdown>
```